# What is the typeface or font that is used for the text of the Moldvay Red Box basic D&D set?

Tags: publishing, dnd-bx, fonts

I'm trying to find the iconic typeface that was used throughout the interiors of the B/X Moldvay Basic D&D set as well as the blue Expert Set. The publication dates pre-date desktop publishing so reasonable facsimiles would be acceptible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Moldvay edition uses Souvenir, according to the unofficial [TSR & WotC Font Usage FAQ](http://www.hahnlibrary.net/rpgs/tsrfonts.html). For other editions, you can check there as well.